# Build spring-boot OCI image with custom UID/GID

Tags: spring-boot, docker, buildpack

I use the `spring-boot-maven-plugin` to generate docker OCI containers with the `build-image` goal.

And the OCI images generated by the paketo buildpack for spring-boot run with the user `cnb`, which has uid/gui `1000:1000`.

Is there a way to customize the user and group id of `cnb`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The uid and guid are defined on the [stack](https://paketo.io/docs/stacks/) used by the paketo buildpacks. You can see this in the [`Dockerfile` for the bionic stack](https://github.com/paketo-buildpacks/stacks/blob/edde18c36e988ad7da926783e49fdf5ab5a8b94b/bionic/cnb/build/Dockerfile#L4-L14).

The only way to override that would be to [create your own stack](https://buildpacks.io/docs/concepts/components/stack/), but that would mean you wouldn't get updates from the Paketo project, and you'd be maintaining your own base OS.